# Function to copy onclick values of different Inputs to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, function, copy, clipboard

I have a Library with different Buttons and want to copy different texts for eacht button when i click it

```
function myFunction(id) {
  var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
  copyText.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}

<div hidden>
<input type="text" value="Text for Button 1" id="button1">
<input type="text" value="Different Text for Button 2" id="button2">
<input type="text" value="Different Text for each Button" id="button3">
</div>

 <button onclick="myFunction('button1')">Click me for text</button> 
 <button onclick="myFunction('button2')">Click me for text</button> 
 <button onclick="myFunction('button3')">Click me for text</button>
```

I expected the Function to work with different ids.

I just need the inputs to have something i can get the text from ill hide them. Actually it is a list of a lot of buttons and when u click one text gets copied to clipboard. Hpefully now it is clearer what i want to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Though it isn't entirely clear from your question, this ought to work in an actual document (where it isn't blocked by the permissions policy)

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  console.log(`running for ${id}`);
  var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
  copyText.select();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Text for Button 1" id="button1" onclick="myFunction('button1')">
<input type="text" value="Different Text for Button 2" id="button2" onclick="myFunction('button2')">
<input type="text" value="Different Text for each Button" id="button3" onclick="myFunction('button3')">
```

Comment: If you must do inline event handling instead of delegation, at least do `onclick="myFunction(this)">`

Comment: @mplungjan agreed, not trying to suggest this is ideal code, rather just trying to keep the code somewhat similar to what was posted, for better or for worse